# Make use of unnamed array

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I am calling an API and successfully getting back an array like this:

```
[ {
  "absmag" : "4.85",
  "speed" : "0",
  "colorb_v" : "0.65",
  "label" : "Sun",
  "appmag" : "-26.72",
  "distance_light_years" : "0",
  "id" : "53794",
  "hipnum" : "0",
  "vy" : "0",
  "updated_at" : "49:09.3",
  "vx" : "0",
  "vz" : "0",
  "texnum" : "1",
  "plxerr" : "0",
  "created_at" : "49:09.3",
  "plx" : "0",
  "dcalc" : "0",
  "z" : "0",
  "luminosity" : "0.8913",
  "y" : "0",
  "x" : "0"
}
 ]
```

How can I reference each of these lines? I'd like to do something like:

```
var database = xml.responseText;
console.log(database.label);
```

Comment: That looks more like JSON than XML...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xml.responseText` is an array, you need to access on the the good index before show `label` :

```
var database = xml.responseText;
console.log(database[0].label); // Add [0] because your example is an array of one element if you have more index refer to the edit
```

If the response is a string, you need to parse the response before use it :

```
var database = JSON.parse(xml.responseText);
console.log(database[0].label);
```

---

**Edit :**

If your array has more than one index, you can use a [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop :

```
database.forEach(function(el) {
    console.log(el.label);
})
```

Comment: how would I get, say, all labels out of the array instead of just [0]?

Answer (score 1):

The key to the answer actually lies in your question . . . that value IS an array . . . a single element array, whose only element is an object.  As such, you have to access the array element like an array (i.e., with an index) and then, since that lone array element is an object, you have to access the object's properties like an object (i.e., with keys).

Using your example code, that would be: `console.log(database[0].label);` . . . `[0]` gets you the first (and only) element of the `database` array and `.label` gets you the value of the "label" property of that object.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you are expecting the resulting array to contain not just one object as depicted by your original question, but it *can* contain a number of objects.

If that is correct then extending the correct answers by @**R3tep**, @**talemyn** and @**trjast**, a loop on top of this array should help as well, IMHO.

```
var database=xml.responseText;
var length=database.length;
for(var i=0;i<length;i+=1){
  console.log(database[i].label);
}
```

Useful?

Answer (score 0):

You could reference the `label` value with

```
var database = xml.responseText[0];  
console.log(database.label);
```